# Remove ServerAlias from httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I am using WHM/cPanel to manage web hosting and wondering how to remove the "cpanel, whm, webmail" ServerAlias. For example, I DO NOT want anyone to do this {HTTP_HOST}/cpanel in order to get to their cPanel.

These rules are clearly defined in the httd.conf file which is located in

```
/usr/local/apache/conf
```

I have already tried to manually modify them and I got the following message:

```
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE 
PLEASE USE THE INCLUDE FILES.
```

Nothing really happened even though the file was successfully saved. Users are still able to use these unwanted aliases. What should I do to effectively make the change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Apache?

```
service httpd graceful
```

.. or you can do it through WHM.

Comment: I tried service httpd graceful but it did not work. How can I do it using WHM?

Comment: Log in to WHM, on the left menu bar at the very bottom you will see 'Restart Services'; click on 'HTTP Server (Apache)', then click 'yes'